# Smaller representations for the group satisfying $\{\sigma_i,\sigma_j \}=2$ and $\sigma_i^2=1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

In recent days after learning about the derivation of [Dirac equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_equation#Mathematical_formulation), I was wondering how the Dirac matrices would look like if one changes the commutation relation from **anti-commute to 0** to **anti-commute to 2** which is the regular coefficient in squared monomials. In other words, what would have being the solutions to the problem

$$\{\sigma_i,\sigma_j\}=\sigma_i\sigma_j+\sigma_j\sigma_i=2$$

$$\sigma_i^2=1 \tag{2}$$

In [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/645483/are-there-any-3-or-more-hermitian-solutions-to-the-problem-alpha-i2-1) the [accepted answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/645842/130986) shows that "this algebra is generated as a vector space by the 8 elements $1, \sigma_1, \sigma_2, \sigma_3, \sigma_1\sigma_2, \sigma_1\sigma_3, \sigma_2\sigma_3, \sigma_1\sigma_2\sigma_3$".

Element $\sigma_1$ being

$$\sigma_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

And "Concretely, what $\sigma_1$ does on the basis is $e_1\mapsto e_2, e_2\mapsto e_1, e_3\mapsto e_5, e_4\mapsto e_6, e_5\mapsto e_3, e_6\mapsto e_4, e_7\mapsto e_8, e_8\mapsto e_7$"

However, these are $8 \times 8$ matrices and I'm now looking for the smallest possible representation of these matrices, for a better comparison with [Pauli’s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices) ($3$, $2 \times 2$) or [Dirac’s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices) ($4$, $4 \times 4$) matrices.

I’d like to inform that this is not a question about physics. I’m looking for the pure mathematical solution to the minimal representation of the solutions to the posed problem only.

Any help will be appreciated.

---

**PS:** Quotes are text originally posted in the cited answer.

Comment: What does $\{\sigma_i, \sigma_j\}=2$ (i'm assuming two times identity matrix on RHS?) have to do with commutativity? The matrices $\sigma_i$ and $\sigma_j$ commuting means that $\sigma_i\sigma_j=\sigma_j\sigma_i$ which translates to $\{\sigma_i,\sigma_j\}=2\sigma_i\sigma_j$, when $\{A,B\}=AB+BA$. It is better expressed as $[\sigma_i,\sigma_j]=0$ where $[A,B]=AB-BA$ is the commutator.

Comment: With these relations the smallest representation is surely 1-dimensional. Each and every $\sigma_j$ can be mapped to either $+1$ or $-1$.

Comment: @J.Manuel The relations in the question you linked *do not* imply that $\sigma_i$ and $\sigma_j$ commute.

Comment: @Christoph Haa! I get you. I truly messed up my reasoning. What I truly want is to find the solutions of the problem $\{\sigma_i,\sigma_j\} = 2$, in particular $\sigma_i^2 = 1$ and not to commute. Your right!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes there is the trivial solution :) I noticed that as well. However, do the 8 matrices found in the original answer (which I now added to the body of current question) do have a smaller matrix representation?

 The existence of this real number 1 representation excludes any matrix representation other than the $8 \times 8$ presented here? Thanks.